# LTspice: Plot energy efficiency in the same window with volt and amp graphs

Tags: ltspice

I am trying to draw energy-efficiency in the wave-plotter. Like what you get using `.meas` and `.param` commands (as seen in the schematic), but plotted.
I want to have the efficiency of the circuit together with the other waves in the same windows because I want to quickly change components and see how that changes the efficiency. (Theoretically)

Circuit:
[image]
[image] https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WAiPilCNFHLMNI6gvyyoom95Kz3YYDTR?usp=sharing

The `.meas` commands use the average of the whole waveform as the basis of the calculation of efficiency:
`pin: AVG(-v(vbat)*i(staticbattery))=0.0487199 FROM 0 TO 2
pout: AVG(v(vled,vled2)*i(led))=0.0305857 FROM 0 TO 2
efficiency: 100/pin*pout=62.7785`
I could plot or look at this in a separate window - with an irritating amount of clicks everytime I change a component - sure. But I want a line or wave together with the other measurements in one window.

So I was trying to put battery-milli-Watts in relation to LED-milli-Watts, to get a factor in %, in the plot window.
Why isn't it as easy as `(100 / BATmW) * LEDmW`? **It seems like wave peaks and troughs interfere and put the calculation off.**
For example, this calculation doesn't work: `(100 / (V(VBAT)*-I(StaticBattery)/1mW)) * (V(VLED,VLED2)*I(Led)/1mW)` (I use `/1mW` to get rid of the unit)
That gives me a graph that could be useful if clicking it with CTRL WOULD show the correct average - But it shows a value of 241.52. The waveform has peaks in the ten-thousands, pointing at interference. So it's useless.

How do I create the same behavior as `100 / averageIN * averageOUT = efficiency` in the plot-view window? Since the "AVG" command does not work in there, unfortunately, I need a different solution.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you post your Ltspice schematic and waveforms?
Clicking with CTRL should give the correct average

Comment: done. I don't know if you need ALL the symbol files, but I included the one I made myself.

Comment: "But it shows a value above 100". Suppose you have a circuit whose only effect is to delay the delivery of power to a load: you put in a constant power pin from ti to tf, and your load gets the whole power from ti+tdelay to tf+tdelay. Would you agree in saying that this circuit has 100% efficiency? Now, try to plot pout/pin*100. What is the average of that curve?

Comment: It would help to just post the schematic so I don't have to try to open it in Ltspice.

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant. Unclear. I'll do it

Comment: Sredni: Now, try to plot pout/pin*100. What is the average of that curve?    If you mean that in my circuit, it is identical with 100/pin*pout, 241.52. I didn't get the rest, atm. How do you even delay power?

Comment: Compute the average of the simple, ideal circuit I gave you. Does the average of pout/pin*100 give the result you expected, i.e. 100% efficiency?

Comment: I just realized there is no such thing as a "constant power pin" and i was just reading this totally wrong. xD I still don't get it.

Comment: I found eomething called "Tdelay(s)" in AC source, while trying to do whatever... I still have not the slightest clue what you want me to do. xD

Comment: I meant you should do that with pencil and paper, to discover that the average of the quotient of two functions (pin(t) and pout(t)) is not the same thing as the quotient of their averages.

Comment: I think I got it... You mean like that? https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WYSHtwFVh-3AeJqiIxtdqTwj2miqnXdM   ---   Btw I still don't know what you mean with delaying power. EDIT: Oops. Was too late with my edit.

Comment: I am not sure what this circuit does, it appears to be a simple boost converter that oscillates on its own. It could be as Sredni pointed out that the input and output power are not in phase. What happens if you take the average of just the input power and output power separately?

Comment: EE_socal then this happens `100 / (60.742mW/1mW) * (36.733mW/1mW) = 60,4738`. Yes, It is a joule thief. I want to change the NPN and see the changes in efficiency on the plot.

Comment: I don't get your math. What is the input power and what is the output power?

Comment: @SredniVashtar I think you want to point out what I was trying to say myself using "It seems like wave peaks and troughs interfere." Am I right?

Comment: @EE_socal Input is first mW, 60.742. It is identical with `(100/(V(VBAT)*-I(Battery)/1mW))*(V(VLED,VLED2)*I(Led)/1mW)`, that's why I thought it is not necessary to clarify that further. The "/1mW" is just there to get rid of the mW unit in the plot

Comment: Yep: compute the average powers, then the efficiency. Average over an integer multiple of periods.

Comment: I think you meant 60.4738. Using a comma instead of period is confusing. So that is the efficiency.

Comment: @SredniVashtar Ok yes. How to make that happen in the plot view, is basically my question.  EE_socal: Oops. That was automatic, I'm german. Didn't see that. You're right it should be a dot.

Comment: Take a look at this, not sure but may help: http://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-using-meas-and-step-commands-to-calculate-efficiency.html

Comment: Also here: http://ltwiki.org/index.php5?title=Efficiency_Report

Comment: @EE_socal No it does not. (First link) If you've read my question or the link you would've seen that I am doing this already (yellow text on the left in the picture and in my text), but I want to do THAT in the Plot window, without steps.

Comment: Are you kidding me?! "(This section is currently blank. Contributors of LTwiki will replace this text with their entries.)" Please read the links you're posting! EDIT: Ok I found the hostory of that wiki page. I am going through that. :D EDIT: Because my Circuit is AC, the simulator does not register a Steady state, therefore I cannot use that feature.

Comment: Sorry that did not help, good luck.

Comment: @all I guess it was hard to read and understand or whatever. I cleared it up quite a bit now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LTSpice's waveform viewer won't integrate for you, but LTSpice itself will.

Use a capacitor to integrate a behavioral current source

[image]

Then you can plot V(Eout)/V(Ein)

[image]

Comment: +1 This is so nice: an analog computer that... computes the ratio of two moving averages. Of course the glitch at the beginning happens before integration covers at least a full cycle of periodic behavior.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are doing there? Why does "I=..." work in a current source in your program, but not in mine? I get "Fatal Error: Missing current value". Where do I even put these floating circuits? Why are they floating? Why are both ends of them going to ground? Why do they have the name "B1, B2" and not "I1, I2", are they not current sources? What does ".ic V(Ein) = 0" do? Are these ".ic ..." SPICE directives? Are you not using LTspice? Why not??

Comment: An alternative is a simple behavioural source with `idt( -I(Vin)*V(in) ) / idt( I(D3)*V(out) )`. A bit more complex would be using `idt( 0, 0, idt(...) )` which acts like a sample & hold, giving a straight line over a cycle (and delayed by a cycle). @Distelzombie It looks like you're very new to LTspice, it would be better to first learn about it, then try making schematics.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I am new and I am trying to learn about it; But no, there is no information about my question available online or else I wouldn't need to ask it. Furthermore, he provided an answer that could have the bare minimum of information needed for someone who is very experienced with this program to replicate, but not for someone like me OR the broad audience that comes after. Adding to that is, that he appears to be using a different SPICE program, where commands like "I=-I(Vin)*V(in)" work as an expression in a current source - or whatever that nondisclosed part of the circuit is.

Comment: Why do I find literally three seconds later, after sending the comment above, the exact part he is using? Because you @aconcernedcitizen mentioned behavioral current sources. How would was I supposed to find that out with such limited information given? It it not a good answer in the sense that it was not descriptive - at all - about its solution, which might be perfect.

Comment: (I meant: the solution might be perfect, but not recreatable.) ... It still doesn't work because for some reason `I=I(LED)*V(VLED, n004)` gives: `Fatal Error: B2 calls unknown device named i(led)` but the LED is called LED ... It makes no sense. It would make sense however, if he is using a different program where calling a device like this works. And @aconcernedcitizen "Fatal Error:  Unknown parameter "idt". after trying to use that inside the behavioral current source  `idt( -I(StaticBattery)*V(VBAT) ) / idt( I(LED)*V(VLED, n004) )`

Comment: @Distelzombie I mean absolutely no offense when I say try reading the manual, from the beginning. It's very terse in some places, but it provides the basic info about the functionality of LTspice. Not knowing about behavioural sources means you don't know about the basic elements, not knowing how to write an expression (`I(LED)`, for ex.), means you don't know the correct syntax, same about `idt`. I am just pointing out that these things can be learned by simply pressing `F1` and reading about them, and trying to make schematics with a program you don't know doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I'll just add that people answering here are doing so because the question, itself, is about something you do with LTspice, which seems to imply a certain basic knowledge about it. That's why the answer you got may seem without explanation, or oriented for "savvy" people, but it's actually not, because for someone who has the basic knowledge it would make sense. Your questions imply a desire to learn about the program and its usage, rather than specific parts that do not work because of the schematic.

Comment: An answer that the questioner cannot understand is obviously a waste of time for everybody. Much like commenting on a lack of knowledge regarding answers that simply don't work. You've both given me commands. They don't work when I use them myself. Do you expect me to read through a book, because a guy who answered my question has chosen to do it in an unclear way, instead of asking again? You both could have articulated your answers in a way that they are usable as is, without spending much more time. The secretive way you've chosen to leave out vital information is unbearably irritating.

Comment: In your OP you use LTspice to draw a schematic, plot, perform various activities that *imply* at least a basic knowledge about the program. Yet you ask questions that are basic. I recommended reading the manual, it has a good enough introduction, instead you choose to point the finger at both of us and call us secretive. There is no secret, there is only basic knowledge that you don't know, but have been pointed at for reading. Your choice: either read to learn, or blame us for "hiding" explanations from you. The answer can be understood by anyone with basic knowledge, no waste of time.

Comment: I meant the nature of your answers is secretive if I need extra information to apply exactly what you've said under identical circumstances. For example the codes and expressions that don't work when I use them in the same place with the same context. (As far as I know. Maybe the idt and the other command is used when simulating using netlists and not as an expression of the "I" value in a behavioral current source in gui, but I don't know this small, shortly describable detail) I will take a look into the manual later, whenever I want to read something bland, mostly uninteresting. :P xD

Comment: B is a behavioral current source. You can read about it in the manual, section LTSpice->Circuit Elements->B. Arbitrary Behavioral Voltage or Current Sources

Comment: .IC is an initial condition SPICE directive. You can read about it in section LTSpice->Dot Commands->.IC -- Set Initial Conditions

Comment: While this is part of the "circuit" simulated by LTSpice, it's only related by the expression for the behavioral source. It will have no effect on the rest of your circuit.

Comment: @Distelzombie "How would was I supposed to find that out with such limited information given?" in the answer I said "Use a capacitor to integrate a **behavioral current source**"

Comment: I'm not being secretive, but I'm not going to give a step-by-step tutorial either.

Comment: @Distelzombie, what tek did is to exploit the fact that the voltage across a capacitor is the integral of the current 'through' it. By creating a circuit with C=1, zero initial conditions, and a current equal to the expression you want to integrate, you will end up with a voltage across the capacitor that is the integral of that expression. So, those circuits are just a 'calculator', actually an analog computer, that you place nearby your actual circuit to produce the signal (in this case the numerator and denominator of the efficiency curve) that you want to plot.

Comment: @Distelzombie , as to why you are getting the "unknown device" error, I do not know. The technique works on my JT in LTSpiceIV. To avoid typing errors, I went into the wave plotter, selected the trace names there and copied them into the I=F(...) cell of the behavioral current sources. If that still does not work, try on a different, simpler circuit.

Comment: @Distelzombie The first letter of a SPICE component name defines its type. You will need to name it DLED or something else starting with D.

Comment: Ok, I got that. The LED has the Prefix "D" and the InstName "LED". I thought that would suffice. (Same with the batterys) It works! However, it is off: `efficiency: 100/pin*pout=62.8006
efficiencybcs: AVG(v(eout)/v(ein)*100)=57.3727 FROM 0 TO 2
offby: efficiency-efficiencybcs=5.42789` Off by 5.42789 when using the average over `.tran 0 4 2 startup` - And off by 4.14488 when using average over `.tran 0 100 2 startup`. I mostly understand why that is, but the efficiency after 98s still is 58.830109% (using the cursor at 98s) This is a little too much. Can I adjust the capacitor somehow?

Comment: @Distelzombie Just use the final value of V(eout)/V(ein), otherwise you're averaging twice. `.meas tran efficiencybcs param V(eout)/V(ein) * 100`

Comment: Ok, but I used the cursor at the end of a 98 seconds simulation and was still only 58.830109% instead of 62.8006%. I changed it nontheless and the new bias is 4.08165. I've reset all settings and added 0s in the capacitor at Rser and so on, but of course that didn't help, because the voltage is measured before it. -- Any ideas?

Comment: @Distelzombie What are V(Ein) and V(Eout) at the start? You're skipping 250ms of startup, right?

Comment: Im skipping 2 seconds to get rid of the ramping in calculations. that 250m was max timestep, which I removed a while ago. If I remove the 2 seconds it just starts at 0 and goes up after 57ms, due to "startup" which is necessary for it to work.

Comment: @τεκ I tried some things. Yet I cannot get rid of the ... what is it called? If something is off by a certain amount? "Bias" is wrong. Ah, you know what I mean. :D

Comment: @Distelzombie Decrease the minimum timestep. 100us should simulate plenty fast.

Comment: @τεκ I already said I removed that a while ago. There's nothing set anymore. And I needed the 250ms or more for something to work back then.

Comment: @Distelzombie Set it to 100u. The default is 1/50 of the simulation time (so 100ms). It is the *maximum* timestep.

Comment: @τεκ That worked... I tried to understand why that is, but 5.4 seems a little too big for "decreased resolution". Maybe I should just read the damned manual already. xD If I ignore anything from the start the difference goes up to 0.81, but changing the length doesn't affect the difference (There's a better word for it. I can't remember... dis-...argh)  -  So, it is either 0.0175329 with 100µs or 0.00672519 with 50µs max. timestep. Totally irrelevant and 100µs is fast. Great! I love it! I love you! xD